# js setHours - countdown parameter format 

Tags: jquery, time, countdown

I am trying to modify a script to run a countdown every 5 mins. Currently a getCountDown() function is set to counting down every 12 hours. I cant seems to figure out how to modify this time format to count down every 5 mins.
The function I need to change is here

```
function getCountDown() {
var until = getGMT();
until.setHours(until.getHours() < 12 ? 12 : 24, 0, 0, 0); // Next midday or midnight
return until;

function getGMT() {
var now = new Date();
now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + now.getTimezoneOffset() - 0 * 60); // GMT is UTC-0
return now;
```

}

My js skills are very limited so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does `getGMT` look like? What properties does `until` have? We'll need to see that code as well.

Comment: do you just need the javascript or do you now know what algorithm to use? Do you understand the code that you have pasted and how that is working or is the problem that you don't understand the current functionality so can't change it to what you want now?

Comment: ok the getGMT function is added above. Yes the problem is I dont understand the current functionality so I can figure out how to change it.

Comment: @ajm: until looks like a Date object from the sethours and getHours methods. I assume that getGMT does what it says on the tin and returns a Date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This answer is intended to guide the poster to the solution and a better understanding of JS, not to give the solution.

The way the current code works is by first getting a date object and then setting the time on that object to either 24:00 (next midnight) or 12:00 (next noon). It works this out by checking what the current hours value is for the time (<12 means noon is next, otehrwise midnight is next). It then returns that newly modified date object showing the date that I presume the countdown is designed to run until.

So the core of the problem is you need to return a different date object which means you want to set the minutes to something of your choosing (and the seconds and milliseconds to 0).

For what you want to do you would be wanting to use the getMinutes and setMinutes functions on the Date Object to check the current date and then set the appropriate minute (and seconds and milliseconds values). Of course if your current time is 01:59 then you may need to change the hours to give 02:00 so you may in fact still want to use setHours (since this does allow you to set hours and minutes).

To work out what your new minutes value is will hopefully be something you can do. You jsut need to round up to the nearest 5 and deal appropriately with the above mentioned situation where you are rounding up to an hour.

Documentation on these above methods can be found on the msdn site:

- [setHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a5xhxy%28v=vs.94%29)
- [getHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/815z9tc9%28v=vs.94%29)
- [getMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t919zcb7%28v=vs.94%29)
- [setMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3sbd2ey3%28v=vs.94%29)

**Edit to add some code**

```
var hours = until.getHours();
var minutes = until.getMinutes();
var targetMinutes = Math.ceil((minutes+1)/5)*5;
if (targetMinutes==60)
{
    targetMinutes = 0;
    hours = hours+1;
}

until.setHours(hours, targetMinutes, 0, 0);
```

You might be able to write the above a little more efficiently and you might need to check what it does around boundaries like midnight properly too (it seems to work but you should always test code thoroughly). Hopefully you can understand what its up to. :)

Comment: Thank you for this help. I will take this away and try and work it out myself. Thanks again for the advice it is much appreciated. I will post answer if I solve it.

Comment: If you do have any problems or can't solve it I am willing to try to knock up a quick solution. I always prefer to answer these more general questions by pointing people in the right direction rather than just giving the answer to copy/paste. :) (and feel free to +1 my answer if it helped).

Comment: yes I understand - its much better to let me try myself. I will hopefully figure it out but to be honest I am quite confused.

Comment: I'd start off by making sure you understand the methods involved (that I linked to, hopefully correctly) and remember that what is being returned from there is the end point of your countdown (I presume at least). good luck. :)

Comment: @ Chris: I have read through the documentation that you posted and I have also read about the Ternary Operator in an attempt to modify the format of the original parameter into what I need. So I'm trying to return what 5mins is using the getHours method like  until.setHours(until.getHours() < 0.0833 ? 0.0833 : 0, 5, 0, 0). Unfortunately I think this is a little beyond what I can currently understand. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: I think this case may be more complicated than a one liner... I'll put some rough code in my answer in a sec but don't have a lot of time to thoroughly test it right now...

Comment: @ Chris:Thanks so much your time on this. I integrated you code into mine and its nearly working but not quite - Im trying to figure out why its not looping from 5mins, I will edit your code if I get it right. - http://files.perfectday.gb.com/internal/stackoverflow/countdown/

Comment: Ah, the problem is that at: 13:50:01 (ie one second past that time) the calculations for minute will work out the next minutes as being 50 and so not go on to the next stop. The fix is to add one to your minutes before the rounding operation (code edited). This ensures that it will never return the current minute as the targetMinute. Try that and see how it goes.

Comment: @ Chris: Thats perfect!! I cant thank you enough for you help with this. Your a great man!!

Comment: I did it all to get past the 8k rep mark. ;-) Glad it all works. Have fun with it. :)